# monitor internet bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth, monitoring

I'm looking for a windows tool that can tell me who is using bandwith.

As of now I've setup so that the switch where all pcs are connected, mirrors the router's traffic to my pc, meaning that from my NIC I am able to see all outgoing and incoming internet connections.

This works, I have used NIMAS (http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/200) and I am able to see internet traffic.

Now what I am looking for is something even more simple, where I can see what computers are using what banwidth, live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Ntop](http://www.ntop.org)

Comment: Ntop for windows doesn't seem to be free (the non limited packet version)

Comment: You did not specify that you are looking for a "free" tool, however, you can build a linux box out of any old desktop, put free Ntop on it and mirror network port from to that box, instead of your windows desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to share the data from multiple PCs, but [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) is an excellent bandwidth monitoring and shaping tool.

Comment: I just tested, only works for local processes and not for other computers

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WireShark.](http://www.wireshark.org/)
It may fit your needs.
It can filter by IP and is in real time. You can actually see each packet go through.

Comment: Do you have any reference, it seems more like a packet inspector than a bandwith monitor...

Comment: Yah it is primarily for packet monitoring.
May not be as simple as other options that were suggested but wanted to inform you of it.